# How to Install laravel/scout on Lumen with mysql driver?

Tags: lumen, laravel-scout

Steps to install laravel/scout on Lumen framework (there are some additional steps that you need to do to make it work with lumen opposed to Laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install laravel

```
composer require laravel/scout
```

Register the service provider in the bootstrap/app.php in the provider section

```
$app->register(Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class);
```

Copy the configuration file (you may be able to do it with composer `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"` , I wasn't)

```
cp vendor/laravel/scout/config/scout.php config/scout.php
```

Ask lumen to load the configuration file, adding this line to boostrap/app.php

```
$app->configure('scout');
```

Install laravel mysql mysql driver

```
composer require yab/laravel-scout-mysql-driver
```

Change the driver setting in config/scout.php

```
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'mysql'),
```

Append this to config/scout.php

```
 'mysql' => [
        'mode' => 'NATURAL_LANGUAGE',
        'model_directories' => [app_path()],
        'min_search_length' => 0,
        'min_fulltext_search_length' => 4,
        'min_fulltext_search_fallback' => 'LIKE',
        'query_expansion' => false
    ]
```

run the scout index if plan to use in NATURAL_LANGUAGE or BOOLEAN

```
php artisan scout:mysql-index
```

Use like this

```
Model::search(searchString)->get();
```

You can also add other conditions

```
Model::search(searchString)->where(...)->get()
```

Comment: Thanks man, you're amazing!!! I didn't know mysql-driver, and didn't how to implement another driver, without Angolia

Answer (score 0):

According to the above answer,this line:
`'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'mysql'),`
cause an error which was "Driver [mysql] not supported".

For solving the problem use "database" instead of "mysql" as a driver.